# MySQLi SELECT queries for related records

Tags: mysql, select

Ok, I have edited my message and included the code for the second query as suggested in your replies. I have also included a screenshort of what is expected of the result; which is:

1. The offender's photo and bio data
2. The photo of any other offenders linked to the offender in the first SELECT query statement.

Could this be your suggestion?

```
<?php
 //The first working MySQLi SELECT statement is here .....

    }

    /* Close the statement */
    $stmt->close();
}
else {
    /* Error */
    printf("Prepared Statement Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT PersonID,ImagePath FROM t_persons 
                NATURAL JOIN t_incidents
                NATURAL JOIN t_incident_persons 
        WHERE t_persons.PersonID = '$PersonID' AND t_incident_persons.IncidentID = t_incident.IncidentID")) {   

    /* Execute the prepared Statement */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* Bind results to variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($PersonID,$ImagePath);

    /* fetch values */
    while ($rows = $stmt->fetch()) {
     // display records in a table
     <?php echo '<img src="./Persons_Images/'.$ImagePath.'" width="300" height="400" border="1" />';  ?>
     }
     }
/* close our connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

The expected results should be:

[image]

Comment: can you please write your expected output in question?

Answer (score 0):

> Perform a natural join for the tables

```
select ('coulmns in need') from t_persons natural join t_incidents natural join t_incident_persons;
```